# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate proper use

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am attempting to teach myself Node.js using Express and Mongoose.

The portion of the site that I am working on is a polling system and I've gotten everything working save for one small (though rather important part) tracking users votes...

I have a poll handler that contains this code

```
pollVote : function(req, res, next) { //needs poll name, user, and their vote
    Polls.findOne({'active' : true},  function(err, poll) {
        if(err)
            throw err;

        if(poll) {
            if(poll.users.indexOf(req.user.userData.username) > -1) {
                req.polls.response = "You have already voted...";
                next();
            } else {
                var index = poll.labels.indexOf(req.polls.vote);
                var voteIndex = {};
                voteIndex['votes.' + index];
                var query = {'active' : true};
                var update = {$inc : {voteIndex : 1}, $push : {users : req.user.userData.username}};
                var options = {};
                Polls.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, poll){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    req.polls.response = "Voted";
                    next();
                });


            }           
        } else {
            req.polls.response = "FAILED";
            next();
        }
    });
},

prepVote : function(req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body.stringData;
    data = data.split(',');
    var name = data[0];
    var vote = data[1];
    req.polls = {
        name : name,
        vote : vote,
        response : ""
    }
    next();

},
```

This is called by my router like so

```
app.post('/poll-vote', requestedOn, isLoggedIn, pollHandler.prepVote, pollHandler.pollVote, function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.polls.response);
});
```

My Mongoose Schema is like so

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var pollSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name        : String,
active      : Boolean,
users       : [String],
labels      : [String], 
votes       : [Number],
answerDesc  : [String],
created     : Date,
deactivated : Date

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Polls', pollSchema);
```

When I attempt to vote I get a MongoError stating " '$inc' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$inc: {< field >: ...}} However that's how I have it set up yes?

I've scoured quite a few different entries on here and the Mongoose API. I was originally attempting to do this with a save but it wasn't saving my changes.

I come from a SQL background so this document based DB system is a little confusing. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to increment `votes` instead of `voteIndex`? `voteIndex` is not in your Schema for the `Poll` model.

Comment: @roflmyeggo voteIndex is a variable that I set to ['votes.' + index] where index is the indexOf the label the user chose on the poll.

Comment: `$inc` is used to increment the field in the database on the found document. This is the function of `findOneAndUpdate`. :)

Comment: yes but how do I indicate the correct element of the array 'votes' I don't know at execution which element to increment, I'm trying to match it up to the elements in the labels array so that I can generate accurate results later.

Comment: I see. Try adding it just as a string, without the Object notation.

Comment: changed to var voteIndex = 'votes.' + index;   same error

Comment: What happens if you replace `voteIndex` with `'votes.0'` in the database query?

Comment: that worked so something is going on with me using a variable to represent that string... can you not use a variable to represent the string in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to increment a subfield in the `votes` field then you can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) that MongoDB specifies.

> **$inc**
>
> The $inc operator increments a field by a specified value and has the following form:
>
> `{ $inc: { <field1>: <amount1>, <field2>: <amount2>, ... } }`
>
> To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use *dot notation*.

See this example regarding the use of *dot notation* with `$inc`.

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "abc123" },
   { $inc: { quantity: -2, "metrics.orders": 1 } }
)
```

The problem for you lies in how you are specifying the *dot notation*. You cannot use `var voteIndex = 'votes.' + index` because you cannot use anything other than constant strings in object literal syntax.

You have two options:

1) With newer versions of `Node.js` that incorporate parts of the `EMCAScript 2015 (ES6)` specification you can use the `[exp]: value` syntax as shown below.

```
var update = {$inc : {["votes.${index}"] : 1}, $push : {users : req.user.userData.username}};
```

2) In older versions of `Node.js` you can create the `Object` prior to using it with `$inc`.

```
var index = poll.labels.indexOf(req.polls.vote);
var voteIndex = {};
voteIndex['votes.' + index] = 1;
var query = {'active' : true};
var update = {$inc : voteIndex, $push : {users : req.user.userData.username}};
```

Comment: gah so close... I made the change and it looked like it was about to work.
looks like {$inc: {["votes.${index}"] : 1} now however I get the error: cannot use the part (votes of votes.${index}) to traverse the element ({votes: [0, 0]})

Comment: The second one did it! though I downloaded node.js just three weeks ago, odd that it would already be outdated? Thanks so much for your help and patience